# Setting up localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I store multiple data in `localStorage`? Using an array doesn't seem to work.

```
for(i=0;i<8;i++){
   localStorage.vals[i]= item[i]; //vals[i] does not work
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`setItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) and [`getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) methods of [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Set the `Object` in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

```
var data = {};
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    data[vals[i]] = item[i];
}
localStorage.setItem('myData', JSON.stringify(data));
```

To `get` it:

```
var myData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myData'));
```

**Update**

To check if `data` already exists in `localStorage`:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('myData')) {
    // Already Exists
}
```

Comment: haha...its been twice I am about to answer and you answer jst before me...BTW...its correct buddy :)

Comment: Will localStorage data overwrite same JOSN objects? Just want to know if the same JSON objects will hold the latest data if a user makes a change.

Comment: @Bekki If you use same key e.g. `myData` to store data it'll override the previous data

Comment: just one more question. How can I write an `if()` statement to check if `myData` is already stored?

Answer (score 3):

LocalStorage can only store string data.

You could store your arrays and objects in JSON format though:

```
localStorage.vals = JSON.stringify(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to this answer there are lot of custom created storages for HTML5 available in GitHub:

1. https://github.com/alekseykulikov/storage
2. https://github.com/aaronagray/omg

You can go through the below mentioned article for the complete understanding of localStorage in HTML5:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/